# I have an arabic website, but my target keyword impression mostly searched from non Arabic country, India

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

In search console, One of my target keywords with very high impressions mostly seen from a country with non arabic language, India. 
it is very strange, and also the google trends show different result. why somethings like this happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set your desired country from Google Search Console and add "hreflang" to your site. Even after adding all this, people can search your website from all around the world. Searches from India can be the people who know Arabic.

But if you want to show your website only in the Middle East then you have to block all of the countries except the ones you want to show.

If you chose not to block, then you will be getting visitors from all around the world, and i think that is completely fine as Arabic speaking people are all around the world.

Comment: I set a target country,Oman, in international targeting section on search console, but I would like to target more than one country, but there was only one country option to choose, How I can do this?

Comment: Google allows only one country targeting for a single URL. If you wish to target two countries, you will have to create a sub domain for the second country to target that.

Comment: Is it good to specify a target location, or leave it blank ? all arabian countries for us are the same value,

Comment: I think, you should leave it blank.